# Is a HDD removed from RAID 1 bootable?

Tags: raid1, remove

I'm having a problem with my RAID. It has gone wrong during a power outage of the server.

I have a server with 2x 500 GB WD HDDs on Hardware  RAID1(SuperMicro Server) with a Linux OS installed on it. My RAID status is "Rebuild" and as I see the server boots and works only with one HDD.The other HDD works as HDD but not with RAID 1.

My question is : What can i do if i want to destroy the RAID 1 and use the functional HDD to boot and work with the system??

I will remove the other HDD from the system and use it for my own purpose

Comment: Do you no longer want the RAID 1 array? Has something changed in your requirements?

Comment: No i don't want to use the RAID1 anymore.i just want to remove the hdd that is not operating.Remove the HDDs from being memebrs of RAID1 and make the system bootable only from the good HDD (1 HDD).Is this possible ?

Answer (score 3):

If a true hw raid1 of the whole drive, it should be bootable.  If the mirror is at the partition level or even some kind of metadata level, then it may miss the boot block in the first 512 bytes (actually I think it is less even).

Comment: Yes the RAID is BIOS assisted.So i made the RAID 1 on BIOS and the i booted from RAID and installed my actual Linux OS on it.So it means i can destroy the RAID and boot only from one HDD ?